# Is there any projection that doesn’t clamp values when calling toLonLat()?

Tags: openlayers, map-projections, openlayers-5

In OpenLayers 5, when getting the view extent using `const extent = this.view.calculateExtent(this.map.getSize())` and then converting it to `latLng` using `toLonLat()` the result values are clamped (-180 to 180 for longitudes) if the map is at a very low zoom level.

Is there any way of avoiding this clamping, like for example using another projection, or another function?

Comment: You can use `ol.proj.transform(`) or `ol.proj.transformExtent()` to transform to 'EPSG:4326'.  Unlike `toLonLat()` they won't normalise the longitude.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer myself. Looking at the code `toLonLat()` applies a transform equivalent to `transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326')` and then clamps the Longitude. So the answer is to use `transform()` instead of `toLonLat()`. Additionally, there is also a `transformExtent()` function.